# how to rearrange a split for a input

Tags: python

I have a task to rearrange a sentence with the first name middle initial and last name to last first middle. I don't know how to do this without a stated search or how to make a index. Ive tried it with finding a space between but I don't know how I would rearrange doing this. This is what I have but it doesn't work. If I could get help defining each part I think I could do the rest on my own.

```
name = input("Enter a name like 'First I. Last: ")
index = name.find(" ")
rearranged = name[3:index]
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function on a `str`?

Comment: Yeah but we havent gone over that yet so i dont know how to use it

Comment: `f, m, l = name.split(" ")` then you can return them in any order! `print(" ".join((l, m, f))`

Comment: "but we havent gone over that yet so i dont know how to use it" Did you know that there is documentation built right into Python at the interpreter prompt? Try `help(str.split)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Python 3.8+, you should be able to use it like this:

```py
name = 'John C. Smith'

rearranged_name = ' '.join([(word := name.split(' '))[2], *word[:2]])

print(rearranged_name)
```

Note that in the above, you could also write out `*word[:2]` like `word[0], word[1]` if you prefer to be more explicit.

Output:

```
Smith John C.
```

If you're using an earlier version than 3.8, the following alternative should still work for your use case (adapted from a comment by @TheLazyScripter).

```py
*rest, last = name.split(' ')

rearranged_name = ' '.join([last, *rest])
```

Where `*rest` can also be reworded as two separate variables - `first, mi`.

Comment: This seems like a particularly pointless and show-offy use of `:=`, certainly not worth restricting to code to 3.8+.

Comment: I agree, it's kind of a snobbish one-liner lol. But I personally do like it, as I think it looks cool.

Comment: I added an alternative approach for pre-3.8, just in case :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you expect an exact number of fields, you could assign them directly to names

```py
first, middle_i, last = input("Enter a name like 'First I. Last': ").split()
```

However, you'll probably find it better/easier to use a regular expression to let the fields be optional or write some other custom parser

```py
import re
name = input("Enter a name like 'First I. Last': ")
match = re.match(r"(?P<first>\w+) (?:(?P<middle>\w\.) )?(?P<last>\w+)", name)
if not match:
    raise ValueError(f"name is invalid: {name}")
# match.groupdict() is a dict with the members named in it now
```

```py
>>> name = input("Enter a name like 'First I. Last': ")
Enter a name like 'First I. Last': a b. c
>>> name
'a b. c'
>>> match = re.match(r"(?P<first>\w+) (?:(?P<middle>\w\.) )?(?P<last>\w+)", name)
>>> match.groupdict()
{'first': 'a', 'middle': 'b.', 'last': 'c'}
...
>>> name = "foo bar"
...
>>> match.groupdict()
{'first': 'foo', 'middle': None, 'last': 'bar'}
```